# Algorithm to determine whether two (Gram) matrices are congruent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algorithms, integer-lattices

Let $G, G'$ be two symmetric (and positive definite) $n \times n$ real matrices, thought as being some Gram matrices.

> Is there an efficient algorithm to decide whether there exists $U \in \mathrm{GL}_n(\Bbb Z)$ such that $G' = {}^{t} U \cdot G \cdot U$ ?

Checking whether two matrices are *similar* can be done using Jordan normal form I guess, but for congruence (which I thought was called 'equivalence') I don't know. Apparently LLL reduction is not sufficient.

Comment: @Masacroso : similarity means $G' = U^{-1} G U$, so I don't think I am wrong.

Comment: This is a very difficult problem for "large" $n$. Theoretically one can use Minkowski reduction, but practically LLL as a heuristic is invaluable.